# Using XmlDocument or XPath to query nodes

Tags: xml, linq, xpath, xmldocument

Given the following sample xml, how do I query all nodes with the Attribute/Value: type='sometype'

```
<root>
    <a type='sometype' />
    <b>
        <c type='sometype'/>
        <d>
            <e type='sometype'/>
        </d>
    </b>
</root>
```

Comment: what if the attribute has a namespace such as "xsi:type" on it how do you define or update the following xpath to ignore the namespace?
"//*[@type='sometype']"

Comment: The following will do it but it also returns sibling nodes of root if root has siblings:

"//*[@*[local-name()='type']='sometype']"

How can I include only descendants of root?

Comment: Do you need to keep the hierarchy?  If so you need a recursive method for parsing the xml.